# Preenchendo tabela

Tags: php, javascript, array

Tenho uma função, porém não sei como fazer com que ela reconheça dados com mais de um registro vinculado a um código, por exemplo tenho esse código de produto `ABITA`e ele tem 5 tipos e descrições vinculados a ele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém na minha `function` só consigo buscar o primeiro ou o último registro, que seria o `ID` 516 ou `ID` 520. Existe a possibilidade de eu preencher esta tabela abaixo com dados corretos vindos do banco de dados de uma forma que cada linha receba um registro ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

index.php

```
<form action='salvar.php' method='POST'>   

    <div class='form-group col-lg-4'>
        <label>  <b>Descrição:</b> </label> <!-- Não é enviado para o banco só está sendo utilizado para preencher os campos a partir deste -->
        <input type="text" maxlength="20"  name="descri"><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group col-lg-4'>
        <label>  <b>Código do Produto:</b> </label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="15"  name="codigo_produto"><br><br>
    </div>

    <table border="2"><!-- Iniciando a Tabela -->

        <thead>
            <tr><!-- Início dos Títulos da Tabela / Cabeçalho -->
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>                                                                                                              
            </tr><!-- Fim dos Títulos da Tabela / Cabeçalho -->
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){ //coloquei este valor para testar ?>        
                <tr>
                    <?php              
                        $sql_tipo = "SELECT * FROM tipoprod ";
                        $resulta = $conn->query($sql_tipo);
                        $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();
                            echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
                    ?> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="codigo_tipo[]"</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="descricao[]" </td> 

                </tr>
           <?php } ?>
        </tbody>

    </table><br>

    <div class='form-group col-lg-3'><!-- Inicio Botão para efetuar registro no Banco de Dados -->
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="enviar_tipo" value="Salvar Informações">
    </div>

</form>
```

functionx.php

```
<?php
include_once("conn.php");

function retorna($descricao, $conn){
    // Utilizando JOIN para trazer dados de mais de uma tabela 
    $result = "SELECT A.descricao, B.id, B.codigo_produto, B.codigo_tipo, B.descricao FROM CADPRO A"
            . " LEFT OUTER JOIN TIPOPROD B ON (A.CODIGO_PRODUTO = B.CODIGO_PRODUTO) WHERE A.descricao = '$descricao' "; 

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

    // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
    $valores = array();

    // Realiza o preenchimento dos campos a partir da descricao do produto informado
    if($resultado){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);           
        $valores['codigo_produto'] = $row['codigo_produto'];
        $valores['id'] = $row['id'];
        $valores['codigo_tipo'] = $row['codigo_tipo'];
        $valores['descricao'] = $row['descricao'];


    } else {
        return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
    }

    return json_encode($valores);                
}

if(isset($_GET['descricao'])){
    echo retorna($_GET['descricao'], $conn);
}
?>
```

tabela infoprod

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, Vitor! Conseguiria nos fornecer a estrutura de suas tabelas no banco de dados? Assim fica mais fácil de verificarmos onde está o problema, provavelmente está no seu select, mas fica mais fácil se tivermos a estrutura das tabelas.

Comment: creio que se fosse erro no select a função não retornaria os dados, correto ?  Estou achando que dentro da function tenho que fazer um while ou um loop for para percorrer os dados da tabela porém não consigo fazer. vou editar a pergunta com a estrutura da tabela infoprod

Comment: Legal.... vou dar uma olhada, creio que me expressei mal quanto ao erro no select, kkk.... quis dizer na lógica do select e não no select em si... rs você consegue colocar a estrutura da tipoprod também?

Answer (score 1):

Bom...

Na realidade estava meio equivocado com o erro nos comentários acima, vamos aos códigos, rs.

```
<tbody>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){ //coloquei este valor para testar ?>        
        <tr>
            <?php              
                $sql_tipo = "SELECT * FROM tipoprod ";
                $resulta = $conn->query($sql_tipo);
                $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();
                    echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
            ?> 
            <td><input type="text" name="codigo_tipo[]"</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="descricao[]" </td> 

        </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Neste trecho que você enviou, observe que você está sempre pegando somente o primeiro resultado.
O correto seria você criar um laço para percorrer cada um dos resultados, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
$sql_tipo = "SELECT * FROM tipoprod ";
$resulta = $conn->query($sql_tipo);
?>
<tbody>
    <?php while($row = $resulta->fetch_assoc()) : // Enquanto houver registro ele roda o while ?>        
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id'];?>"></td>';
            <td><input type="text" name="codigo_tipo[]" value="<?=$row['codigo_tipo'];?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="descricao[]" value="<?=$row['descricao'];?>"> </td> 

        </tr>
   <?php endwhile ?>
</tbody>
```

Tente verificar essas alterações se funcionam para você.

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu até sei fazer desta forma, o que eu queria era que a partir do usuário escrever a descricao o outros campos fossem completados automaticamente, e desta forma eu percorrerei a tabela toda buscando todos registros

Comment: Eu também notei a falta do looping na consulta sql, conforme resposta do @RodrigoTeixieraAndreotti, mas agora no seu comentário fiquei na dúvida do que realmente está precisando, poderia editar a pergunta e explicar está dúvida, assim outras pessoas também podem te ajudar.

Comment: Assim como o @WagnerFernandoMomesso também fiquei meio na dúvida agora, pois para mim pareceu que você estava tendo problemas para popular a tabela com os dados do seu select, porém agora me parece está querendo popular a tabela a partir de uma entrada do usuário, se for isso realmente, creio que você precisará de algumas alterações no seu código.

Comment: então é basicamente isso, no campo descrição o usuário irá informar a descrição do produto, então eu não consigo trazer todos registros vinculados ao produto na tela, só o primeiro, queria saber como alterar o código pra fazer isso

Comment: O código corrigido que postei se aplica também a este caso, você precisará alterar sua consulta para utilizar um where e consultar a descrição.
O arquivo functionx.php que você postou, de certa forma está fazendo isso, porém ele não está sendo usado na construção da sua tabela, então você precisará fazer essa alteração na query que você está utilizando, e usar o laço da mesma forma como apontei

Comment: Mas neste caso teria que incluir o meu ID, na busca da clausula where, porém ja tentei isso e nao deu, mas de qualquer forma obrigado, mesmo nao atendendo a pergunta